# In SSAS Data Source View, the DimDate and FactInternetSales with tables in AdventureWorks Database has no relationships between

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am a SQL Server Developer familier with SSIS. But it is my first time to work on SSAS. I am trying to learn it from free video tutorials offered by Microsoft. In the tutorial When they try to create Data Source View with tables in AdventureWorks Database ..the schema had relationships between DimDate and FactInternetSales(with 3 connecting columns/lines) while other tables have one connecting column/line.

```
But when i tried to do the same, the schema shows no relationship between DimDate and FactInternetSales. Note: Other tables had one connectivity ..same as the video tutorial.
```

Please advice.

Thanks,
Vanu

Answer (score 0):

There must be a 1-to-1 relationship between the Fact date keys and the DimDate dimension. So, in your example, there were three connecting pointers in the schema view, meaning the Fact table must contain three different date keys.
 This could be something like Start_Date_Key, End_Date_Key, As_of_Date_Key, which could all point to the DimDate.Date_Key key field. With this in mind, your row would look something like the following

Start_Date_Key = 20120101
As_of_Date_Key = 20120605
End_Date_Key = 20150101
SomeotherKey = 10
Sales_Product_Key = 5

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You very much. Yes... your reply helps. So since my tables dont have relationships, i need create them manually.(for eg: Start_Date_Key, End_Date_Key, As_of_Date_Key of factinternetsales needs to be pointed to dimdate.date_key field)